# How to iterate over position through Numpy- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am wondering if there is a way to iterate over individual positions in a sequence list using NumPy. For example, if I had a list of sequences:

```
a = ['AGHT','THIS','OWKF']
```

The function would be able to go through each individual characters in their position. So for the first sequence 'AGHT', it would be broken down into 'A','G','H','T'. The ultimate goal is to create individual grids based on character abundance in each one of these sequences. So far I have only been able to make a loop that goes through each character, but I need this in NumPy:

```
b = np.array(a)
for c in b:
    for d in c: 
        print(d)
```

I would prefer this in NumPy, but if there are other ways I would like to know as well. Thanks!

Comment: For iteration, lists are better.  And numpy doesn't add much to string handling.

Answer (score 1):

`list` expands a string into a list:

```
In [406]: a = ['AGHT','THIS','OWKF']
In [407]: [list(item) for item in a]
Out[407]: [['A', 'G', 'H', 'T'], ['T', 'H', 'I', 'S'], ['O', 'W', 'K', 'F']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join()` to join the array into a sequence of characters, then iterate over each character or print it like this:

```py
>>> a = ['AGHT','THIS','OWKF']
>>> print(''.join(a)) 
'AGHTTHISOWKF'
```

Or to turn it into an array of individual characters:

```py
>>> out = ''.join(a)
>>> b = np.array(list(out))
array(['A', 'G', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'I', 'S', 'O', 'W', 'K', 'F'],
      dtype='<U1')
```